# I am getting this error while running my runner class for Cucumber project. Error : java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type Cucumber not present

Tags: cucumber

i have been trying to solve this issue for more than 3 days now, but did not find any luck, i am getting this error saying java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type Cucumber not present,  i have changed version of my dependencies and tried consistent version of all cucumber dependencies, can anyone please help me on this issue?
Here is my runner file:
package Runner;

````
        import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
        
        enter code here
        
        import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
        import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
        
        @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
        @CucumberOptions(
                features="features"
                .glue= {"stepDefinition"}
                )
        public class TestRunner {
        
        }
        ```
````

Here is my POM

````
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        
            <groupId>Freecrm.com</groupId>
            <artifactId>Freecrm.com</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        
            <name>Freecrm.com</name>
            <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
            <url>http://www.example.com</url>
        
            <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
                <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
            </properties>
        
            <dependencies>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.6</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-core -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.6</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.6</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.6</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.masterthought/cucumber-reporting -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                    <version>3.141.59</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        
            <build>
                <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                        defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
                    <plugins>
                        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.2</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.8.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.22.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.2</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.5.2</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8.2</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.7.1</version>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0</version>
                        </plugin>`enter code here`
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </project>


        ```
````

Comment: Replace `.` from `@CucumberOptions(features="features".glue= {"stepDefinition"})` with `,`

Comment: @DilipMeghwal    Still i am getting same error      import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  features="features",
  glue= {"stepDefinition"}
  )

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are using really old versions of Cucumber; please use more recent versions so we can help you better. Second, you are using multiple different versions of Cucumber for different dependencies (Please don't do that as it will lead to unexpected problems). Third, you are adding dependencies that will be imported as transitive dependencies.

To help solve your problem:

1. Please check the [Cucumber docs on how to install Cucumber-jvm](https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/) for the dependencies you need and their latest version.
2. Make sure your dependencies are imported (you may have to refresh maven or enable auto-import in your IDE).